# Hoja de Estilos no reaccionan: PHP y CSS3

Tags: php, html, css

Disculpen, ultimamente he estado trabajando con PHP, y me he dado cuenta de algo.

Cada vez que cambio de  a  me cambia el estilo de ese boton. Hasta ahi lo entiendo, porque el estilo dice "button{...}", pero luego, aunque le ponga el "input[type=button]{...}", sigue sin tomar el estilo.

También, me sucede que derrepente algunas cosas pierden su lugar(dejaré una imagen para que vean). Espero que me puedan explicar el por qué suceden éste tipo de cosas.

Código de HTML en la barra de Navegacion:

```
<body>
  <div class="Navegacion">
    <aside class="nav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><img src = "img/logo.png"</li>
          <li> <a href="nomina1 lobby.html">Inicio</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="nomina2 busqueda.html">Registros</a> </li>
          <footer id="f"> <a href="../Inicio.php">Cerrar Sesión</a> </footer>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  </div>
```

Codigo CSS de barra de Navegación:

```
.Navegacion{
  color:#000;
  font-family: Verdana, "Geneva", sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  width: 15%;
  height: 97.5%;
  font-size: 90%;
  background-color: rgba(200,200,200, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  margin:0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Código HTML del boton.

```
<div class="Confirmaciones">
    <label id="Confirmacion">Confirmaciones</label><br><br>
    <label>Entrada:</label>
    <label><?php echo $row['firmaEntrada']; ?></label><br><br>
    <label>Salida:</label>
    <label><?php echo $row['firmaSalida']; ?></label><br><br>
    <label>Receso:</label>
    <label><?php echo $row['firmaReceso']; ?></label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <?php  } ?>
      <div class="Botones">
        <button type="button" name="Enviar"> <a href="promotor registro general.php">Volver</a></button>
      </div>
```

Código CSS del boton:

```
button[type="button"]{
  border-radius: 4px;
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 33%;
  left:30%;
  background-color: rgba(10,20,70,1);
  color:white;
  font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  left: 27%;
  position: absolute;
}
button[type="button"]:hover{
  background-color: rgba(15,30,80,1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Confirmaciones{
  font-size: 75%;
  left:40%;
  top: 60%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Aquí se pone el botón sobre un label que dice "Salida:

[image]

Aquí se pone un color mas claro del gris fuera del div, son como 15px extras que se marcan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así deberia ser.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta poner "!important" (sin comillas) al final de cada propiedad de tu clase css.

Comment: No funciona, de hecho, lo cambio a html el archivo y si funcionan los estilos correctos(tampoco me deja editar, pero funcionan los estilos)

Comment: Sería ideal que copies tu codigo HTML y CSS para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Habría que ver el código para saber que ocurre exactamente. Respecto a lo del botón hablas de los selectores `button` e `input[type=button]` que hacen referencia a dos elementos html distintos: `<button>` y `<input type="button>`

Comment: Editare el post inicial para que puedan ver el codigo.

Comment: Editare el post inicial para que puedan ver el codigo.

Comment: A ver si entendi cuando pasas de un enlace a otro cambia el color de los botones Intenta ver si tienes el mismo archivo css enlazado en los dos archivo o revisa si tienes un echo o var_dump antes de cargar el html o mejor aun abre en inspector de tu navegador y revisa si el head no se mezclo con el body

Comment: **Montaycabe** tiene razón. Debes repasar las bases de HTML y CSS. El código hace lo que le dices, si no lo entiendes puede que te pierdas un poco intentando averiguar lo que está sucediendo. Las indicaciones que te ha dado son básicas. Un **link dentro de una etiqueta button**. **Espacios en los destinos** de los enlaces. Etiquetas **img** sin cerrar. La etiqueta **footer** como si fuera un **elemento li** Tal vez primero repasaría un poco sobre CSS y HTML en [w3schools CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) / [w3schools HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) y ver ejemplo

Comment: Estatas dandole un atributo type a una etiqueta button, el atributo type solo funciona en input

Answer (score 2):

Estas usando un a dentro de un button y posiblemente se estan pisando los estilos. Da igual que cambies el estilo del button si dentro hay un `<a>` con sus propios estilos.

Ademas creo que te estas liando:

- Has metido un button con "enviar" (pero sin asociar a un form ni
  direccion), y dentro del boton un link a "volver", eso no tiene
  sentido.
- Dentro de los href de `<a>` hay espacios, eso no te va a funcionar tampoco.
- La etiqueta `<img>` está sin cerrar.
- Los `<label>` estan sin asociar y sospecho que le estas aplicando la etiqueta a campos.
- Has metido un `<footer>` dentro de un `<ul>`

Deberias pegarle un repaso en profundidad a todo...